# Srv2K3R2 to Srv2K8R2 migration redirected folders with user exclusive rights robocopy access issue

Tags: dfs, migration, folder-redirection

Trying to migrate users My Documents and Desktop redirected folders where the users have exclusive rights to the folders. Using Robocopy with /e and /copyall attributes running as domain admin. Access is denied. This is from Server 2003 to Server 2008 R2. DFS is running but replication won't work between the machines. Any thoughts?

Comment: If the users have "exclusive" access rights to the folders, surely that means the account you're running robocopy as will not have rights?

Comment: Yes, that's why I brought it up. I'm looking for a way around that that doesn't include taking ownership. Like running robocopy through a batch file as a scheduled task under NT Authority. (Haven't been able to get that to work)

Comment: Is there a reason you are preventing the Domain Admins account from NTFS and/or Share permissions on the redirected folders? You should be able to give permissions to the parent folder and let inheritance set permissions for the children. That should allow you to robocopy with your options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the wrong way to do this (as in, you probably want to use the file server migration tool or handle this through Group Policy, or get DFS replication working), but [if you insist on using robocopy, you want the `/zb` switch](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).

> /ZB : Use restartable mode; if access denied use Backup mode.